# Add Label To Cell on Certain Rows only

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I have a lot of rows with a few different layouts - that all works fine. Now I want to add a Custom `UILabel` on just some of the rows. I know that there is a "problem" working with a reuse identifier, so the `UITableView` will try to reuse my `UILabel` on the next Cells again. To prevent this, I've checked a lot of suggestions here and tried it this way:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell? {

    var cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myQuestions.getQuestion(indexPath.row).qTemplate, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    // if there is a saved Notice, add this to this Cell

    if(myQuestions.getQuestion(indexPath.row).qNotice != nil) {

        cell.addNoticeToCell("This is a Test")

    }

    return cell

}
```

And my `CustomTableViewCell` class is:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var LabelCellTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var TextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var LabelCellContent: UILabel!

    var noticeButton:UIButton!

    func addNoticeToCell(noticeText: String) {

        noticeButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        noticeButton.frame = CGRectMake(330,44,600,44)
        noticeButton.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        noticeButton.tag = 100
        noticeButton.setTitle(noticeText, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.contentView.addSubview(noticeButton)

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {

             println("CELL BEFORE REUSE")

             if(self.contentView.subviews.count > 0) {
                 for mySubView in self.contentView.subviews {

                     if mySubView.tag == 100 {

                         mySubView.removeFromSuperview()

                      ....
```

It works now as expected - but I  don't know if its a good idea to go through all subviews. Is there a better way? I would add 2-3 `UIImageView`s on certain cells too, and would create it with the same procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `prepareForReuse()`, why not just use the property you added to your cell class to remove it rather than enumerating all of the subviews like so:

```
var noticeButton:UIButton?

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    if let notice = self.noticeButton {
        notice.removeFromSuperview()
        self.notice = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ive tried this first but it give me always an Error: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That's because you have noticeButton as an implicitly unwrapped optional when it should be treated as a normal optional. I'll update my response

Comment: Ok Thank you - i got it. I changed your text to: self.noticeButton = nil - it works now as expected!